# HTML - First `ul` child

Tags: html

I have an  `ul` with a few `li`s, but even without CSS, the first `li` pans outside the list...
Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eggNK/)

I really can't figure out what's causing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed the closing anchor tag

```
 <a id="scroll_1" name="scroll_1" style="top: 100px; margin: 100px;"></a>
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eggNK/2/)

Comment: Well that was simple... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

update the tag `"<a></a>"` code as below:

```
<a id="scroll_1" name="scroll_1" style="top: 100px; margin: 100px;"></a>
```

Updated your fiddle also

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. Did you already try to fix with css?

```
ul li:first-child {
 margin-left:0 !important;
 padding-left:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Check the answer above.